# Problem with Reselect when adding new item to a large array

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I'm using [Reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) to create various selectors for React + Redux. I run into performance problems when I have over 1M items, the selector computation might take from 300ms to 500ms, since it has to filter and sort through all the items with expensive checks.

I'm [normalizing](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape) the state in Redux, where I have the items stored in `byIds`, and the ids stored in `allIds`. This is all fine. But when I add a new item, `byIds` and `allIds` will be updated, meaning that the selector will have to re-compute all the 1M items again, instead of just computing the new item.

Is there some smart way to solve this, or something I'm missing. Previously I didn't use any selectors. This meant that I filtered all new items before they were added to the store, but this had the side effect of my data not being pure.

Some methods that I've thought about is re-structuring my data or creating some kind of layers for the data where I can better memoize part of it.

Here's the structure of my selectors:

1. getVisiblePostsIds - gets `postsIds` which has the id of all items and filters them. E.g. an item that is blocked or of the wrong type should be filtered out.
2. getSortedPostsIds - gets `getVisiblePostsIds` and sorts the items by a condition
3. getFilteredPostsIds - gets `getSortedPostsIds` and slices the items array if there are too many items.

Here's the rough source code if it might help.

```
const getVisiblePostsIds = createSelector(
    [
        getFeedsByIds,
        getPostsIds,
        getPostsByIds,
        getFeedType,
        getStartDate,
        getModerationDict,
    ],
    (
        feedsByIds,
        postsIds,
        postsByIds,
        feedType,
        startTime,
        moderationDict,
    ) => {
        return postsIds.filter(
            postId =>
                postsByIds[postId].created >= startTime
                && feedsByIds[postsByIds[postId].feedId].IgnoreStartDate === false
                && moderationDict[postsByIds[postId].mediaId] === undefined
                && moderationDict[postsByIds[postId].userId] === undefined
                && (feedType === FEED_TYPE.SHOW_BOTH
                    || (feedType === FEED_TYPE.SHOW_MEDIA_FEED_ONLY && postsByIds[postId].type > 1)
                    || (feedType === FEED_TYPE.SHOW_TEXT_FEED_ONLY && postsByIds[postId].type === POST_TYPE.TEXT)),
        )
    },
)

const getSortedPostsIds = createSelector(
    [
        getSlideArrangement,
        getVisiblePostsIds,
        getPostsByIds,
    ],
    (
        slideArrangement,
        postsIds,
        postsByIds,
        // .slice() is supposed to be faster than [...postIds] to clone the array without mutation
    ) => postsIds.slice().sort(comparePosts(postsByIds, slideArrangement)),
)

export const getFilteredPostsIds = createSelector(
    [
        getSortedPostsIds,
        getHasLoopLimit,
        getLoopLimit,
        getSlideArrangement,
    ],
    (
        postsIds,
        hasLoopLimit,
        loopLimit,
        slideArrangement,
    ) => {
        ...array slice
    },
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: do any of the dependency selectors take props? like `getSomething(state, { prop1: 'foo' })`?

Comment: No props, just state.

Comment: the only thing I can think of is maybe one of the dependency selectors is given a larger-than-necessary chunk of state, causing recalculations on updates it doesn't need to know about

Comment: I'm always passing itemsIds and itemsByIds to almost every selector. I wonder if that could be the issue, but I have no other way to access the item object itself unless I get ref to itemsByIds. Am I perhaps thinking this wrong.

Comment: after you get the ids, do you pass them to a component that maps them to an array of components that each accept an id?

Comment: In this particular case I'm not mapping them to any component. Just doing pure performance test on the selector itself. I need to nail that down first. But eventually the component will only receive the id and it'll map the byIds[id] for itself